# Failed connect to database on Laravel Forge with Workbench

Tags: mysql, laravel, workbench, forge, laravel-forge

I I want to connect my GUI Workbench  in SSH for my server Laravel Forge with private key but it failed. In connection ssh, it works! An idea please? (see screenshots)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the MySQL server [allow remote connections](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/remote-connection-to-mysql)?

Comment: Yes i comment #bind-address = 127.0.0.1. I can connect mysql on server but not with SSH Tunnel on Workbench :(

Comment: OK, the server is not bound to the loopback address, but that's only half the story. Does the `forge` user you're trying to connect with also have remote access? Run this query in your MySQL CLI `SELECT concat_ws('@', User, Host)  FROM mysql.user;` and see if there's a listing with `forge@%` or `forge@your-ip-address`?

Comment: Yes it's good! I see  forge@%                    |
| root@%                     |
| forge@46.101.34.74         |
| root@46.101.34.74

Comment: Does it work if you try to connect remotely using a password instead of a SSH key?

Comment: It(s not work when i whant to connect with SSH on port 22 with Laravel Forge Server :( Enable ssh on server?

Comment: Obviously if you need to connect over SSH, the service needs to be running on the server. And you need to [copy the public SSH key](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the MySQL Hostname to localhost/127.0.0.1 try setting it to your server's IP (46.101.34.74 in your case).

I ran into the same issue, tried that out of desperation and it works. Basically setting the SSH Tunnel to connect to an IP that is itself? Not sure.